# Using ninject with repositories, in mvc 5 ef 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I set up my first mvc project with ninject, and im not sure if i understand this fully. I have the following simple setup.
I am using entity framework 6 as my orm.

**Customer repository**

```
 public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
 {
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;

    public CustomerRepository(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll()
    {
        return this.db.Customers.ToList();
    }

}
```

**ICustomerRepository**

```
  public interface ICustomerRepository
  {
    IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll();
  }
```

**Ninject**

```
   private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<ICustomerRepository>().To<CustomerRepository>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<ICustomerDetailsRepository>().To<CustomerDetailsRepository>().InRequestScope();

        kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().To<ApplicationDbContext>().InRequestScope();
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 public HomeController(ICustomerRepository customerRepository, ICustomerDetailsRepository customerDetailsRepository)
    {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
        this.customerDetailsRepository = customerDetailsRepository;

    }
```

As you can see, i am calling both repositories from the same controller. Both repositories are setup exactly the same way.
**Will both my repositories use the same dbcontext when requested, and will it automaticly be disposed afterwards??**

This is not a real life setup. I made it really basic to try and understand how ninject work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you configured your binding to be [`InRequestScope`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope) means that the requested object will be created the first time it's resolved after a new request starts, and for every subsequent resolutions of the same object within the same request, you will get the same instance.

Keep in mind that the lifetime of the request is determined by the lifetime of the `HttpContext.Current` object.

Just for reference:

As you can see [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Infrastructure/StandardScopeCallbacks.cs):

- `InThreadScope` matches the lifetime of your object to the lifetime of `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread`
- `InSingletonScope` matches the lifetime of your object to the lifetime of Ninject's `Kernel`
- `InTransientScope` matches the lifetime of your object to the lifetime of `null`

## Update

Regarding your comment about people implementing `Dispose()`:
Even if you don't dispose your objects manually, when the dependency injection container disposes your object, it calls the `dispose` method if it implements `IDisposable`

Comment: Thank you for you answer.  -  I just cant shake the feeling that i have to dispose the context manually.. - But from what i have been reading, ninject will take care of that also, is that correct ?? If we use this concrete example

Comment: Yes, that is correct. One other thing to point out is that you should really consider not calling ToList on the DbSet, it loads all de records to your application. And also changing the return type to IQueriable<T>, that way you're using entity framework's extensions which translate those queries to sql instead of executing in your app

Comment: Did my answer answer your question? If so, you might consider marking it as accepted http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thank you for the answer. :) - I still have a lot of reading up to do. But what i wanted to know in this question was the lifetime of the dbcontext, and as you explained, it would dispose itself.

Comment: Iwe been looking more into it. It seems to me that many people implement dispose method in their repository, even when using ninject or autofac? - I really for the life cant figure out if what i have written really will dispose of the repository.